# How to pass system properties from gradle to JVM?

Tags: java, gradle

I try to use SystemProperties in the testing project, but can't get any in the code.

The CLI command:

```
gradle uitests -Dbrowser=chrome
```

Project structure:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ test/
│  │  ├─ java/
│  │  │  ├─ LoginTest.java
│  │  │  ├─ BaseTest.java
│  │  ├─ resources/
│  │  │  ├─ login.feature
├─build.gradle
```

- build.gradle:

```
tasks.withType(Test){
    systemProperty 'browser', System.getProperty('browser')
    println systemProperties.get('browser') <------------------------(1)
}

task uitests() {
    dependsOn assemble, testClasses
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = [
                    '--plugin', 'pretty',
                    '--plugin', 'html:target/cucumber-report.html',
                    '--glue', myproject.steps',
                    'src/test/resources/scenarios']
        }
    }
}
```

So, line (1) printed the correct parameter that I need, but when I try to get this parameter in the code with `System.getProperty("browser");` I get `null`

Answer (score 1):

because -D JVM param is limited to the gradle JVM only, it will NOT be auto passed to the `javaexec` that has been created manually with specific args.

you have add `jvmArgs = ['-Dbrowser='+System.getProperty('browser')]`
see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html